# jquery ie9 file upload does nothing

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to allow our IE9 users to upload a file and it's not working. All the other browsers are working just fine. Nothing appears under the "Network" tab of IE9's dev tools. I've searched Google repeatedly and have tried everything I've read. I'm using jQuery v1.11.0.

My basic watered-down code:

```
<script src="/jquery.iframe-transport.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if gte IE 8]><script src="/jquery.xdr-transport.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="/jquery.fileupload.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$('.upload input[type="file"]').each(function(x, y){
    var $input = $(this);

    $input.fileupload({
        dataType: 'json', //Tried 'html' also
        forceIframeTransport: true,
        redirect: '/html/result.htm?%s', //Tried omitting this also
        url: '//different-domain.com/php/handlers/upload.php',
        add: function(e, data) {
            data.submit(); //Does get executed
        }
    });
});
```

I tried adding the 'done' callback and it never gets hit.

If anyone has any new ideas, I'll appreciate them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IE has a problem with post calls. use GET method to send your call